# Jquery .closest() but how do i unset it on click elsewere?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Gday Guys,

This is probably an elementary answer but i'm struggling to find the answer anywhere.

So i'm using the contenteditable on an  tag to edit and create content on a page i have, and i have removed any borders by the browser. So instead i'm using jquery to change the background of the `<li>` once my `<a>` tag is selected to be edited to show the user what is being  used.

Problem is i can set it using jquery on focus no problem. but once i move on to the next editable tag i'm not sure how to unset the background back to white on the last `<li>`?

Here the jquery im using to set it, any ideas?

```
$( ".list-result-edit" ).focus(function() {
    $(this).closest(".detail-list li").css("background-color", "rgb(203, 255, 207)");
});
```

Comment: Can you show a Demo Link of a jsfiddle or the whole HTML code.

Comment: can't help you without seeing your HTML markup

Comment: http://100percentplumbing.com.au/dashboard/?page=jobcard

First Card, Only been testing in Chrome thus far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the class of clicked `li`

This will solve our problem,

```
$( ".list-result-edit" ).focus(function() {

    $(".detail-list li").css("background-color","-original_color-")
    $(this).closest(".detail-list li").css("background-color", "rgb(203, 255, 207)");
});
```

---

A better solution would be to use `class`.

CSS :

```
.edit{
    background-color : rgb(203, 255, 207);
}
```

JS :

```
$( ".list-result-edit" ).focus(function() {

    $(".detail-list li.edit").removeClass('edit');
    $(this).closest(".detail-list li").addClass('edit');
});
```

Comment: Used the better solution here, Thanks for your advice.

Comment: What would be the best way to remove the green background when clicking anywhere else on the page?

Comment: Try `$(document').click(function(){ $(".detail-list li.edit").removeClass('edit');})` Not sure if it will work.

Comment: Was able to use 

      $(".list-result-edit").focusout(function() {
  $(".detail-list li.edit").removeClass('edit');
 });